# Using a COUNT value generated in a sub query back in the main query

Tags: sql, count

I need to be able to use a count value from this sub-back in the main query.

```
select count(SH2.CUST_ID),
   SH2.CUST_ID 
from sysadm.PS_CUST_SHIPTO SH2 
group by SH2.CUST_ID
```

In the main query, I only want to process customers who have a count of 1.

How can I refer to that in the main query?

Comment: Please edit the tags of your question to include the version of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You usually can use `HAVING COUNT(column) = 1`

to get the customer that only have one row in countr and then join it to the main table.

The result would be all rows in the main that comply with the count = 1 rule

```
SELECT m.CUST_ID,countr
FROM MAIN m
JOIN (
    select
      count(*) countr,
      SH2.CUST_ID 
    from sysadm.countrSH2 
    group by SH2.CUST_ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) c1 OM c1.CUST_ID = m.CUST_ID
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(NonNullValue)` are the same

Comment: That would produce error(s) as well :) Happens to us all if we type in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.*
from myTable t inner join
(select SH2.CUST_ID from sysadm.PS_CUST_SHIPTO SH2 
group by SH2.CUST_ID
having count(SH2.CUST_ID) = 1) x on x.Cust_id = t.Cust_id
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/emIOK8E0)

Comment: that would produce an error

Comment: @nbk, my bad. It was a typo.